# XML within SQL - sql:column removing trailing 0s from a numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am currently trying to insert XML into a SQL table that I use for comparisons between historical records and am encountering an issue that using sql:column on a  numeric datatype column is removing any trailing 0s from the record being put in, causing false comparisons to be made.

The code is something like this:

```
SET Changes.modify('insert <FinancialAmount>{sql:column("c.Value")}</FinancialAmount> after (/Name)[1]')
```

However, a value which is 750.00 in the database is returned as simply 750.

I looked into fn:format-number, but it seemed like it wasn't supported within SQL.

Any advice on how to get around this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely the SQL column is INT datatype which will remove any decimal numbers, Alter SQL table and change the datatype of the column to float or decimal

Comment: I wish it was that simple. The column is datatype numeric(18,2), and comes back with decimals when doing a simple SELECT on the fields

Comment: As you've noticed, there's simply no support in XQuery for formatting numbers, and it will perform potentially unhelpful formatting conversions when the value goes to XML. Use a derived column (`SELECT FORMAT(c.Value, 'G', 'en-US') AS FormattedValue`) and insert that instead. Take care that you're consistent with the formatting string and locale; there's no direct "format as XML compatible" option.

Comment: The key might be here: *using sql:column on a numeric datatype*. I do not know what you are going to do actually but you can introduce a string `750.00` without any transformations. Just format the value *before* you introduce it...